# Left Align all menu items and texts in Android 4.4

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, samsung

It's about Android 4.4. I would like to left align all menus including conversations from Whatsapp for example. How to do it? In fact, I upgraded from version 2.3.1 to version 4.4, and as we know Google made this change of alignment. Is someone unknown?